# execute jdb on linux transport error 202: bind failed

Tags: java, linux, jdb

when I execute jdb on linux, there is an error such as

```
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed
     ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
     JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/back/debugInit.c:690]
     FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
```

my jdk version is jdk_1.6_045

Answer (score 0):

Probably your 510 port is already in use. Try this:

From Linux console execute `netstat -ano | grep 510`.
Take note of the process ID and then execute `kill <PID>`. Try again and it should work...

Comment: It wouldn't be port 510; that's the error code. The default jdb port is 9009.